# How to Insert with in nested schema using node.js?

Tags: jquery, performance, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like:

```
var SchComments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});


var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [SchComments ]
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});
```

How can I insert value to nested schema. How can I call `SchComments` to pass value in `Node.JS`

Comment: How i pass the values to mongodb reading from client. plz suggest some ans so that i can progresss in my work

Comment: i need to insert data to mongoDb using this embedded schema. plz suggest some solution on node.js coding standard

Comment: Read over the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) on this topic and come back with any specific questions you still have.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: i have gone through all mongoose document and i know how to design schema but my problem is how to send my text box value to db through this schema using node.js.. basically i need code on node.js

Comment: That's too broad a question for an SO answer.  If the node.js code shown in the docs isn't enough to get you going, then you probably need to learn more about node.js before continuing.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: i have good command over node.js and so far i put this question to get some good logic  for my question. I never ask for all module in my project..if any good logic plz suggest....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an element to a post's `comments` array, you can either call `push` on the array and then save the change:

```
var post = new BlogPostModel({});
post.comments.push({title: 'a', body: 'b', date: new Date()});
post.save(callback);
```

Or use a [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/#_S_push) operator in an `update`:

```
BlogPostModel.update({}, {$push: {comments: {
    title: 'a2', body: 'b2', date: new Date()
}}}, callback);
```

There are other ways, but those are the most typical.